# Mongo Query: flatten field and split into a new document

Tags: mongodb, d3.js

I am new to MongDB and wanted to change the structure of the collection below using a MongoDB Query:

```
{
[{"id": "raymond_A", 
  "name":"Raymond", 
  "node_updated": 1, 
  "company": "A",
  "token": 50, 
  "time": 152232854211, 
  “links”: ["jason_C", "nick_D" ]
 },
 {"id": "nik_B", 
   "name": "Nik", 
   "node_updated": 1,
   "company": ”B”, 
   "token": 40, 
   "node_time": 1522328542551, 
   "links": ["peter_E", "raymond_A"]
 }]
}
```

such that the final output of the query becomes like the below. Essentially, it splits the links such that the id for each document becomes the the field "source", while the links is flattened and becomes the fields "target".

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "raymond_A”, "name":"Raymond", "node_updated": 1, "company": “A”, "token": 50, “node_time”: 152232854211},
    {"id": "nik_B”, "name": "Nik", "node_updated": 1, "company”:”B”, "token": 40, "node_time": 1522328542551},
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "raymond_A", "target": "jason_C", "link_time": 1522328542561},
    {"source": "raymond_A", "target": "nick_D", "link_time": 1522328542561},
    {"source": "nik_B", "target": "peter_E", "link_time": 1522328542561},
    {"source": "nik_B", "target": "raymond_A", "link_time": 1522328542561}
  ]
}
```

Do kindly advise if I can provide any other information. Thank you.

Comment: How would we know what to put in each document? This is okay for a "mash up" of two documents only, but I presume you have much more documents and they would output to more than **one** as a new document. Without something that indicates how they are to relate, then I don't see a clear way to do this. And surely you're not proposing to put your "entire collection" into a **single document**. Could do with some more explanation, and will lead to only "bad answers" without it.

Comment: Also "please" fix up your UTF-8 quotes. Their not valid, and using a word processor as your editor is really something you should not be doing.

Answer (score 1):

Try below aggregation:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            nodes: {
                $push: { id: "$id", name: "$name", company: "$company", token: "$token", node_time: { $ifNull: [ "$node_time", "$time" ] } }
            },          
            links: { $push: { links: "$links", id: "$id", link_time: { $ifNull: [ "$node_time", "$time" ] } } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            nodes: 1,
            links: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$links",
                    initialValue: [],
                    in: {
                        $concatArrays: [ "$$value", {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$$this.links",
                                as: "link",
                                in: {
                                    source: "$$this.id",
                                    target: "$$link",
                                    link_time: "$$this.link_time"
                                }
                            }
                        } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Basically it looks like you want to merge all your documents into one result so you should use `$group` with constant `_id` value like `null`. Then it's easy to get `nodes` value since it will be flat array after first step. The problem is with links as it's an array of arrays so you need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) to flatten that field.